# Splitting Go App Into Multiple Files for GoLang

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am using the GoLang version of the Go Application Engine to run my website. Mostly for learning.

I am at a point where I want to write multiple Go Service endpoints to support the site (mostly on the admin side). I would like to separate these so that not everything is in the same file (for maintenance sake), but cannot seem to get my head around this.

Is there a way to separate a GoApp in GoLang into multiple files to serve up and handle the incoming requests?

Ideally this would be a single interface style wrapper file that then calls into the more complex methods that are in their own files. I did think about putting the .go files by type into separate folders so that my YAML file could just route, but that does not seem as nice.

Comment: If the files are in the same folder ... then you can split your request handlers into as many files as you want.. is that what you're asking?

Comment: I think so. So in the YAML I would just specify each file that is handling the request? I guess I am not sure how to do it and cannot seem to make my Google skills direct me to the right tutorial/example.

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the files at all. The Go files will be compiled, and the YAML file will just specify the routes etc. handled by the application. (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig). It's initially a bit confusing, but the YAML file really just needs to have a handler for every different http handler in your Go app.

Comment: Rereading your question, I think you should investigate http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc . Basically, if you define a `ServeHTTP` method on anything, then if it satisfies the `HandlerFunc` interface, you can define a route on it with http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handle . Hope that helps.

Comment: That totally makes sense. I figured it was just something I was not fully getting, that solves it for me I think. Thanks for the help! (If you want to put that as an answer, I can give you the vote/answer points as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, in the simplest sense, Go automatically compiles .go files in the same folder when you execute `go build`.

Documentation: http://golang.org/doc/code.html